# Set frame of a UIWebview

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I'm trying to change the size of my UIWebView to fill my view controller. For some reason it is a different size on different devices and the bottom of it extends beneath my tab bars.

I've determined the proper dimensions for the UIWebView Frame and I have a short switch statement for device type.

I'm using CGRectMake to set the frame using this code, but it does not work as it does for normal views. I'm calling it in ViewDidLoad

```
CGRect frame=CGRectMake(0, -17, 320, 382);

self.weber.frame=frame;
```

Comment: Are you setting up your view in a nib/storyboard file?

Comment: "I have a short switch statement for device type"... Please read up on autosizing layouts, you'll save yourself - and us - some pain.

Comment: I've used them before but it isn't working. Do I need a scroll view around it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to fit UIWebview frame

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
self.weber.frame=screenRect;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you size and position anything without autolayout.  Use self.view.frame

```
webView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

Answer (score -2):

Use Following code to set frame of webview:

```
self.webView.delegate = self;
self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
self.title = @"Website";
// NSLog(@"Frame Webview: %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.webView.frame));
self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400);
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:WebUrl];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```